# is there anyway to reuse keys between different objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given that we have a

```
const fooBar = {
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

and another object

```
const fooBarBoom = {
  foo: 'boom'
}
```

is there a way to re-use 'foo' key present in fooBar in fooBarBoom.

Use-case would be to avoid maintaining multiple changes across expected objects.

I know we can do something like

```
var fooBarBoom = {
  [fooBar.foo]: 'boom'
}
```

but that will give us fooBarBoom.bar as key and not fooBarBoom.foo

Comment: If you know the key is "foo" in object "fooBar", why would you not just use the string "foo"? If you *don't* know the name of some property, how would you determine which property of the source object to use? The question is really unclear.

Comment: Lets say these simple examples live in different modules and someone changes one of them to a different key. Therefore, the relation is broken and yes I appreciate that can be caught by a unit / integration test but just to avoid that kind of mismatch

Comment: But that's my point: if the key changes, how would your code know which of the property names in the source object (which might have an arbitrary number of properties) is the one to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
const key = "foo";

const fooBar = {
  [key]: 'bar'
};
const fooBarBoom = {
  [key]: 'boom'
};
```

although a factory function might be a simpler solution for creating objects of the same shape:

```
function make(foo) {
  return {foo};
}

const fooBar = make('bar');
const fooBarBoom = make('boom');
```

Comment: That would work, but then the objects have to live in the same javascript file. I'll update the question, thank you for the input

Comment: @Technoshaft The objects can be instantiated anywhere where `key` or `make` are available (e.g. imported from a shared file)

Comment: The factory function would work but in my case they are enumerations of different types which just have the key shared between them.

Answer (score -1):

Consider [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Shared_symbols_in_the_global_symbol_registry) if your situation allows for it. 
Symbols could be shared globally (run time wide). Given mdn link will help, if you want to explore.

`console.log(Symbol.for('bar') === Symbol.for('bar'));  // true`

Comment: No reason to use `Symbol.for('bar')` over just `'bar'` in the OPs situation.

Comment: That depends on problem size. For a larger problem, symbol will definitely save some heap.

Comment: What "problem", what "heap" are you talking about?